# Proving convergence of sum from another sum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive, monotonically decreasing sequence.
I think that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2^n}$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, but I don't know how to go about proving (or disproving) it.

I have a theorem that says that if $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, and I think the same idea might apply for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2^n}$, but I don't know how to proceed. If someone could show me a way, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You must have more conditions.  Otherwise just take $a_{2^n}=0$ and $a_i=1$ if $i$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Thank you, I added some conditions now!

Comment: Try $a_n=\frac 1n$.

Comment: Good example, thanks! I guess I have my answer now!